# About Global variable for iOS Project

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables

I would like to know how to use Global variable for iOS Project.

Nowadays, I found one document which is writtern by Swift.

This document has some code.

```
import UIKit

let log = ColorLogger.defaultInstance

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

      var window: UIWindow?


      func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
```

This program has only global variablesn which is log.

log is usually used for development,not production.

I think log should be inside appdelegate.

But i don know standard about how to handle variables for iOS Project.

Is using global variables standard for iOS product?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several ways to create "global" variables in Swift, and I will describe some of them.

### **1. Defining variables in `AppDelegate`**

`AppDelegate` seems like a logic place for some global variables. As you said you can create instance of logger or create instance of something else in `AppDelegate`.

To create instance which will be used as a global variable go to the `AppDelegate.swift` and create the variable like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
...
    let myAppInstance = SomeClass()
...
}
```

Then, if you want to access `myAppInstance` in any other part of the application you would write:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.myAppInstance.doSomething()
```

### **2. Creating singletons**

Singletons are probably one of the most used design patters used through any Apple platform. They are present in almost any iOS API you are using when creating application, and they are commonly used to create global variables.

Essentially, singletons are lazy-loaded instances which are only created once. Let's look at the code example:

```
class MyDataStructure {
   static var sharedInstance = MyDataStructure() // This is singleton

   private init() {

   }
}
```

We have created the class `MyDataStructure` and the singleton instance named `sharedInstance`. This is the most common name for the singletons since that singletons are shared instances through the app.

Note the use of the `static` keyword when defining singleton. `static` keyword tells the compiler to create `sharedInstance` only the first time it is being accessed. Any other access to the `sharedInstance` will just reuse instance that is created first time.

To use it you would just write:

```
MyDataStructure.sharedInstance
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am going to use singleton as global variables.

Answer (score 1):

## Defining variable in YourApp.swift :

In project using SwiftUI, the AppDelegate has disapeared. The workflow is now managed with a struct inheriting from App. This is how to create global variable in this scenario :

```
@main
struct YourApp: App {
    static let myGlobalVariable : String = "global"

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Text("View")
        }
    }
}
```

Declare your static variable in the struct managing the workflow. You can then access it later in any file by using :

```
YourApp.myGlobalVariable
```